# Enyo different collection with same model kind

Tags: javascript, enyo

I have been trying to create two collection with a common model kind. I am getting the following error:

"Uncaught enyo.Store.addRecord: duplicate record added to store for kind `app.ImageModel` with primaryKey set to `id` and the same value of `67774271` which cannot coexist for the kind without the `ignoreDuplicates` flag of the store set to `true` ".

Following are the two collection i have defined...

```
enyo.kind({
    name: "app.FeatureCollection",
    kind: "enyo.Collection",
    model: "app.ImageModel",
    defaultSource: "appF",
    ...
    ...
});


enyo.kind({
    name: "app.SearchCollection",
    kind: "enyo.Collection",
    model: "app.ImageModel",
    defaultSource: "appS",
    ...
    ... 
});
```

And the model which i am using is as follows:

```
 enyo.kind({
    name: "app.ImageModel",
    kind: "enyo.Model",
    readOnly: true,
    ....
    ....
 });
```

At one point i am setting like this:

```
this.set("data", new app.FeatureCollection());
```

and in another,

```
this.set("data", new app.SearchCollection());
```

I am not able to find out what could generate the error. I even tried to set "ignoreDuplicates" to true in model...but still the error comes. Any suggestion where i could be going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ignoreDuplicates` flag is expected to be set on `enyo.Store` and not `enyo.Model`:

```
enyo.store.ignoreDuplicates = true;
```

Are you using the `fetch` method of `enyo.Collection` to retrieve your data? If so, you might consider setting the `strategy` property to `merge` in your fetch call so that you have a single record for each unique image from your dataset, i.e.:

```
myCollection.fetch({strategy: "merge", success: function(rec, opts, res) {
    // do something after data is retrieved
}});
```

Comment: Thanks!..And yes you are right about setting "ignoreDuplicates" to true on "enyo.Sore", but may you clarify why this situation is coming? If the data received have some common data as fetched previously, this error comes. For one collection and a model, this doesn't appear, but as i go for two separate collection with a common model, the error comes somehow!

Comment: Are you using a `merge` strategy when initiating a fetch on your collection? This strategy performs a merge within the given collection, so there won't be any duplicate warnings for a single collection, but this issue may arise when multiple collections are backed by the same types of records (in this case, `app.ImageModel`).

Comment: No. I am not specifying the "strategy" to "merge" when initiating a fetch on Collection. Rather, what i think is "merge" is the by default strategy used in "enyo.Store"

Comment: Ah I might have misunderstood your follow-up question. `enyo.store` contains a reference to every `enyo.Model` record loaded into any collection; if there is any overlap, as you saw when loading the same data into two different collections, then `enyo.store` detects this and returns the error you saw.

Comment: Yeah!..Also,in my previous comment i have mistakenly said that by default, strategy used in fetch is "merge". Its not "merge" rather "add". But the main question which is still not answered is why i am not getting error if using a single collection which fetches 4 types of data at runtime, some of them being common.But if using two separate collection, error pops out somehow!

Comment: It might be because the records are instantiated lazily. In the case where you have two separate collections, are you doing anything with the collection upon fetching i.e. binding or using the records in some way? This will cause the records to be instantiated and created in `enyo.store`. Can you try adding the `instanceAllRecords: true` property to your kind definition of your custom collection and see if that results in an error in the single collection case?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing a problem with the pieces of code you provided. I created a sample on jsFiddle and it works as expected.

http://jsfiddle.net/z7WwZ/

Maybe the issue is in some other part of your code?

```
enyo.kind({
    name: "app.FeatureCollection",
    kind: "enyo.Collection",
    model: "app.MyModel"
});


enyo.kind({ 
    name: "app.SearchCollection",
    kind: "enyo.Collection",
    model: "app.MyModel"
});

enyo.kind({
    name: "app.MyModel",
    kind: "enyo.Model",
    readOnly: true,
    defaults: {
        firstName: "Unknown",
        lastName: "Unknown"
    }
});

enyo.kind({
    name: "App",
    components: [],
        bindings: [],
    create: enyo.inherit(function (sup) {
        return function () {
            sup.apply(this, arguments);
            this.collection1 = new app.FeatureCollection(this.data1);
            enyo.log("Collection1(0) >>> " + this.collection1.at(0).get("lastName"));
            this.collection1.at(0).set("lastName", "Smith");
            enyo.log("Collection1(0) >>> " + this.collection1.at(0).get("lastName"));

        this.collection2 = new app.SearchCollection(this.data2);
        enyo.log("Collection2(0) >>> " + this.collection2.at(0).get("lastName"));
        this.collection1.at(0).set("lastName", "Jones");
        enyo.log("Collection2(0) >>> " + this.collection1.at(0).get("lastName"));
        };
    }),
    data1: [{
        firstName: "Hall",
        lastName: "Caldwell"
    }, {
        firstName: "Felicia",
        lastName: "Fitzpatrick"
    }, {
        firstName: "Delgado",
        lastName: "Cole"
    }],

    data2: [{
        firstName: "Alejandra",
        lastName: "Walsh"
    }, {
        firstName: "Marquez",
        lastName: "James"
    }, {
        firstName: "Barr",
        lastName: "Lott"
    }]

});

new App().renderInto(document.body);
```